# How does flutter doctor know what Flutter version to show? (Version: 0.0.0-unknown)

Tags: git, flutter

## Background & Issue

I'm currently working on a Flutter App that requires us to make a modification to the Flutter Engine & Framework. As such, I have a custom-built Flutter Engine on my system, as well as a snap-installed Flutter environment. In order to make and test changes I've made to the Flutter Framework, I've set my remote upstream to my own forked Flutter repository. Now, my issue and the reason for this question, is that whenever I make a change to the Flutter code and cherry-pick some code changes from my forked repo, `flutter doctor` outputs, `0.0.0-unknown` as my Flutter version.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Install flutter using snap (on Ubuntu): `snap install flutter --classic`
2. Run `flutter doctor` to install the flutter tool
3. Fork the `flutter.git` repo in GitHub
4. Open terminal and run `cd ~/snap/flutter/common/flutter`
5. Set your remote upstream to your forked repo: `git remote add upstream git@github.com:<YourRepo>/flutter.git`
6. Checkout the 2.8.1 tag: `git checkout 2.8.1`
7. Run `flutter doctor` and see your version; it should be `2.8.1` (which is correct, obviously)
8. Checkout a new branch: `git checkout -b <your branch>`
9. Make your changes
10. Push your changes to your forked repo (upstream)
11. Run `flutter doctor` and see your version. For me, it was `0.0.0-unknown` even though all my code was the same as 2.8.1 except for a few (fairly minor) changes.

### Final Question

Does anyone know how the Flutter Version is determined? How could the 2.8.1 tag that initially showed 2.8.1 get switched to 0.0.0-unknown only after a few minor changes?

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, it uses git's tagging system to determine what version the code is linked to. Looking at `flutter_tools/lib/src/version.dart`, the `fetchTagsAndUpdate` function gets called, which fetches the current git tags and some other information. It then parses the output string into pieces and determines the version based on that.

The command I used to replicate it was, `git describe --tags`. My tag was un-parsable apparently and was throwing an unknown error. That also explains why as I switched branches and tags, it would change the version output of `flutter doctor`